# How to access property of json object from restful web service

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I need to access the name property of the user object that is returned by a restful web service, so far I can see the object being returned, but I do not know how to access the name property and assign it to a variable

```
User.get.then(function (payload) {
    var usrname = '';
    var usrobj = angular.fromJson(payload.data);

});
```

Can someone please show me how can I assign the property name value, to the variable usrname?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is the name attribute in the first level of the object? if yes:

```
User.get.then(function (payload) {
    var usrname;
    var usrobj = angular.fromJson(payload.data);
    usrname = usrobj.name;
});
```

Comment: taxicala, I will add this to my code soon and let you know. I think it will work, seems basic. Thank you for your help.